# Can you "back date" a European working holiday visa so past Schengen time doesn't count?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, netherlands, working-holiday

Let's say you live in the Netherlands for 3 months on a Schengen and then you apply for a WHV... can you have the start date for that WHV be 2 months earlier, so you get back 2 months of available Schengen time for the rest of the Schengen zone?

Comment: You're asking about backdating, not pro-rating.  Regardless, the answer is no.

Comment: Just work in Ned (or wherever the WHV is from) for a bit, then the ever-rolling nature of 90/180 means you'll be fine again.

Comment: It's conceivable the visa would be back-dated from the date you applied for it (although in this case I don't think it would) but you certainly cannot choose the date yourself for convenience!?